# Marshal inner class with JAXB - Java

Tags: java, jaxb, inner-classes

I followed the following tutorial on JAXB http://blog.adamsbros.org/2010/02/07/jaxb-example-code/, and wanted to modify it to include the class I want to as an nested (inner) class as follows:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext; 
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*; 
import java.io.StringReader; 
import java.io.StringWriter; 

public class HighlevelClass
{


@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee
{

    @XmlAttribute
    public int id;

    @XmlElement
    public
    String firstName;

    @XmlElement
    public
    String middleName;

    @XmlElement
    public
    String lastName;

    public Employee()
    {
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) throws JAXBException
{

    HighlevelClass HClass = new HighlevelClass();
    Employee john = HClass.new Employee();
    john.firstName = "John";
    john.middleName = "Robert";
    john.lastName = "Doe";
    john.id = 1;

    // write it out as XML
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(HighlevelClass.Employee.class);
}
```

But it's giving an eror in the last line when I try to make the JAXB context. I tried number of combinations but I only got it to compile when I made Employee class static.
Can somebody please help me understand whats going wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`main()` method is static, so it can access only static members of your class. It is not a JAXB problem. It is how the language is working.

Inner class is a sort of member. Non static inner class can call non static methods of outer class, i.e. can access the outer class instance (directly using 'HighlevelClass.this' or inderectly by calling methods or accessing fields).

This is why you must define your inner class as static. If you do not want to do this you can either make your class a regular top level class or move your jaxb code to instance method and create instance of your class before using it:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JAXBException {
    new HighlevelClass().jaxbTest();
}


private void jaxbTest() throws JAXBException {

    HighlevelClass HClass = new HighlevelClass();
    Employee john = HClass.new Employee();
    john.firstName = "John";
    john.middleName = "Robert";
    john.lastName = "Doe";
    john.id = 1;

    // write it out as XML
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(HighlevelClass.Employee.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you AlexR. I almost understood the reason. My confusion now is, if I make Employee a regular top level class and call JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class) from the main() method, 'why' would it work? Because main() is static so how would it access non-static members? Why would it work in that case and not in this case? Thank you for your help.